# Why is this function always declaring this property as an empty array?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Why is this newProject() function always declaring the tasks property as an empty array []?

When the page loads, the `` console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`${name}`))) `` is null so the tasks will be declared as an empty array, however when I refresh the page, the `` console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`${name}`))) `` is not null anymore, so the tasks should be declared as `` (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`${name}`))) ``
and not an empty array

```
export const allProjects = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allProjects")) ?? [];


export function newProject(name) {

    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`${name}`))) 
    // Null, when opening page for the first time

    allProjects.push({
        projectTitle: name,
        id: crypto.randomUUID(),
        tasks: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`${name}`)) ?? []
    })
    getProjectId(name)

    localStorage.setItem("allProjects", JSON.stringify(allProjects))
}

newProject("Default")
newProject("random stuff")

export function newTask(projectTitle, title, desc, dueDate, priority) {
    getProjectId(projectTitle)
    project.tasks.push({
        title: title,
        id: crypto.randomUUID(),
        desc: desc,
        dueDate: dueDate,
        priority: priority
    })
    getTaskId(title)

    localStorage.setItem(project.projectTitle, JSON.stringify(project.tasks))
    localStorage.setItem(title, JSON.stringify(task))
}

newTask("Default", "first task", "desc", "due Date", "urgent")
newTask("Default", "second task", "desc", "due date", "no urgent")


// GET ID FUNCTIONS 

export let projectId;
export let project;

export function getProjectId(projectName) {
    project = allProjects.find(obj => obj.projectTitle === projectName)
    projectId = project.id;
    return {
        projectId,
        project
    }
}

export let task;
export let taskId;
export let altTask;

export function getTaskId(taskName) {
    
    
    task = project.tasks.find(task => task.title === taskName)
    altTask = task;
    taskId = task.id;
    
    return task, taskId
}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce [playground](https://tsplay.dev/w16bON). Pressed run a few times, reloaded page, pressed run a few times again. All runs after the first logged an array of objects.

Comment: You call getProjectId but you don't do anything with the returned object.  Same for getTaskId, but the return statement in that func is strange (missing braces?  `return {task, taskId};` ?)

Comment: After creating a task with `newTask`, you don't update the `allProjects` localstorage. You might store the tasks under the title of the project, but on page load you never retrieve those.

Comment: @Bergi how should I do it?

Comment: Just do `localStorage.setItem("allProjects", JSON.stringify(allProjects))` any time you change a value in `allProjects` or the objects contained within them. Don't store anything with dynamic keys - what if I create a task with the name "allProjects"?